# What is the dimensionality of $\phi(x)$ in terms of $n$ in kernel function?

Tags: machine-learning, reproducing-kernel-hilbert-spaces

Kernel Function: $K(x,y) = (b + x^Ty)^2$ is a quadratic polynomial kernel, where $x, y ∈ R^n $and $b > 0$. Provide a feature mapping $\phi(x)$ such that $K(x,y) = \phi(x)^T\phi(y)$. What is the dimensionality of $\phi(x)$ in terms of $n$?

My Answer So far is :
$$\phi(x)= x^tx + \sqrt{2b}x +b $$
And Dimension = $n^2 +n +1$

Comment: kindly include what you have tried.

Answer (score 1):

Good attempt.

\begin{align}K(x,y) &= (b+x^Ty)^2\\&= b^2 + 2bx^Ty + (x^Ty)^2 \\
&= b^2 + 2bx^Ty + \left( \sum_{i=1}^n x_iy_i\right)^2\\
&= b^2 + 2bx^Ty + \sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2 y_i^2 + 2 \sum_{i < j}x_ix_jy_iy_j\end{align}

Hence a possible $\phi$ is

$$\phi(x) = \begin{bmatrix}b \\ \sqrt{2b}x \\ x_1^2 \\\vdots \\ x_n^2 \\ \sqrt{2}x_1x_2 \\ \vdots \\ \sqrt{2}x_{n-1}x_n \end{bmatrix}$$

$\phi$ maps to a space of dimension $$1+2n+\frac{n(n-1)}2$$

---

Comment about your attempt: $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$, $b\in \mathbb{R}$, we can't add a vector to a number.